# Creating hierarchical listFragment in Android

Tags: android, hierarchical-data

I am building a forum-ish app, and need to display the forumposts in a hierarchical manner so that people can easily see which post are responding to (children of) which. Each forumpost has its own object, and this object contains an (int) depth variable which is intended to use for defining its position related to its parent.

I have a BroadcastReciever which takes in the data and sets a listadapter based on the data.
My plan was now to use getListAdapter().getChildAt(position).setLeft(pixels); method for each entry, however i get a nullpointerexception at the setLeft method. My code for this is:

```
            @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String jsonEmner = intent
                    .getStringExtra(RestService.PARAM_OUT_MSG);
            emner = gson.fromJson(jsonEmner, EmneItem[].class);
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), jsonEmner);
            populateEmner();

            int firstID = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int listSize = getListView().getCount();

            for (int count = firstID; count < listSize; count++) {
                EmneItem e = (EmneItem) getListView().getItemAtPosition(count);
                getListView().getChildAt(count).setLeft(e.getDepth());
            }
        }
```

This code is inside the BroadCastReciever method inside the ListFragment class. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction how to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid answering my own question, but I managed to find a workaround in case anyone gets in a similar situation.

I created my own custom ArrayAdapter, and an XML file which defines the layout for the rows. ArrayAdapter has a getView() method which lets you customize each entry, and based on my entries "depth" variable, i set the textviews LayoutParams.

In case anyone wants to see how its done:

```
    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmneItem> {
        CustomAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.row, emner);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;

            //Reusing convertView if possible, if not then inflating a new
            if(row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }

            TextView postedby = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postedbytextview);
            postedby.setText("Posted by: " + emner[position].getPosted_by());

            TextView argument = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.argumentTextView);
            argument.setText(emner[position].getArgument());

            TextView procontratextview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.procontratextview);
            int procontra = emner[position].getProcontra();
            if (procontra == EmneItem.PRO) {
                procontratextview.setText("PRO");
            }
            if (procontra == EmneItem.CONTRA) {
                procontratextview.setText("CONTRA");
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if(emner[position].getDepth() == 1) {
                llp.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
                  procontratextview.setLayoutParams(llp);
                  argument.setLayoutParams(llp);
            } else if (emner[position].getDepth() == 2) {
                  llp.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
                  procontratextview.setLayoutParams(llp);
                  argument.setLayoutParams(llp);
            } else if (emner[position].getDepth() == 3) {
                llp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
                  procontratextview.setLayoutParams(llp);
                  argument.setLayoutParams(llp);
            } else if (emner[position].getDepth() >= 4) {
                llp.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);
                  procontratextview.setLayoutParams(llp);
                  argument.setLayoutParams(llp);
            }
            return (row);
        }
    }
```

This is mostly based on an article i found at http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Cheers